# connecting xampp mysql database to zend framework 3.0.2-dev

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, xampp

I am working with zend framework 3.0.2dev and i following this http://zendframework.github.io/tutorials/getting-started/database-and-models/

Since i am using xampp , i have created the database using http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin 
the name of my database is: myalbums1

in the tutorial link above , he's using php to create a database and then in config/autoload/global.php.....the following code:

```
 return [
    'db' => [
      'driver' => 'Pdo',
       'dsn'    => sprintf('sqlite:%s/data/zftutorial.db', realpath(getcwd())),
   ],
 ];
```

I have edited this to:

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
      'driver'         => 'Pdo',
      'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=myalbums1;host=localhost:8080',
   ),
 );
```

When i enter http://myalbums1:8080/album
it keeps loading forever. the result supposed to be as its shown in the end of the tutorial. I am not sure where the problem is but i am suspecting it has to do something with the database connection. can someone help plz!!

After waiting a while :

> Warning: PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\myAlbums1\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection.php on line 266
>
> Warning: PDO::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=4776 in C:\xampp\htdocs\myAlbums1\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection.php on line 266
>
> Warning: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away' in C:\xampp\htdocs\myAlbums1\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection.php:266 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\myAlbums1\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection.php(266): PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=my...', NULL, NULL, Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\myAlbums1\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo.php(249): Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection->connect() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\myAlbums1\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\Sql\Sql.php(128): Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo->createStatement() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\myAlbums1\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(238): Zend\Db\Sql\Sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select)) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\myAlbums1\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(209): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->executeSelect(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select)) #5 C:\x in C:\xampp\htdocs\myAlbums1\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection.php on line 266
>
> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\myAlbums1\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection.php on line 266